# Extract class into pandas dataframe using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I want to extract the main table of this website (https://coinpaprika.com/longterm?all=true) in order to convert it into a dataframe with these header: Name, Price, 7d, 30d, 1q, 1y.

I am able to get the html code but I can't get the div class section (div class = "cp-table cp-table__coins").

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinpaprika.com/longterm?all=true"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


mydivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class': 'cp-table cp-table__coins'},limit=None)

print(mydivs)
```

Comment: Is the browser page source the same with the output of `response.content`?

Comment: My suggestion is to use APIs instead of web scrapping! check this git repo: https://github.com/s0h3ck/coinpaprika-api-python-client

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This API is perfect!